# Create WebAssembly using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, webassembly

I went through below article

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-started-with-webassembly-using-only-14-lines-of-javascript-b37b6aaca1e4

and very impressed that we can use c++ code in javascript using web assembly.

Do we have any option to create such web assembly using c# where we can create web assembly and use in javascript like angular or react.

went through

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

But that does not look like creating an assembly that can be used in a separate angular only project with by importing

Thanks

Comment: Blazor can use third party javascripts.

Answer (score 2):

From msdn:

**JavaScript interop**

For apps that require third-party JavaScript libraries and browser APIs, Blazor interoperates with JavaScript. Components are capable of using any library or API that JavaScript is able to use. C# code can call into JavaScript code, and JavaScript code can call into C# code. For more information, see JavaScript interop.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0][1]

Ithink looking to Blazor source code can help you to.

Comment: i.e.specific to  app you are developing in .net core.  I am developing a angular only app nothing to c#, Now I need to write some custom code that is very fast in c#, I want to write that code in c# convert to  web assembly and use in my angular app

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for isn't Blazor, because it's a complete UI framework for ASP.NET client/server stuff using SignalR, that uses WASM at the client side. Maybe too much for your purposes, even if you're able to use any JavaScript framework together with Blazor, too.

But you're looking for a simple way to create just a WASM that exports methods to JavaScript that you can write using C#, right? Well, then I suggest you to have a look here:

https://itnext.io/run-c-natively-in-the-browser-through-the-web-assembly-via-mono-wasm-60f3d55dd05a

It seems the Mono way is working as you'd expect: You write methods in C#, compile a WASM and then you're ready to load and call them from any JavaScript client app, and you don't have to deal with ASP.NET stuff at all.

Compared to a WASM that has been created using lower level C++, you'll have a big bunch of DLLs for the Mono runtime, that need to be loaded to the client browser (!). That's a *huge* overhead, if you plan only a small feature set to be exported by the WASM. The best argument for creating WASM using Mono for me is, that I can use my existing codebase with all the algorithms and business logic for a really *complex* app, so I don't have to write and maintenance the same code twice in different languages.